# Rename [star-trek-botf] → [star-trek-birth-of-the-federation]

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, tag-rename-request

In the continued effort to expand tags in light of our 35 character tag limit, I'd like to recommend that we expand the tags for *[Star Trek: Birth of the Federation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Star_Trek:_Birth_of_the_Federation)*.

- [star-trek-botf](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/star-trek-botf) → [star-trek-birth-of-the-federation](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/star-trek-birth-of-the-federation)

It was also published under the names *Star Trek: The Next Generation: Birth of the Federation* and simply *Birth of the Federation*. Given that[star-trek-birth-of-the-federation](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/star-trek-birth-of-the-federation) is already 33 characters, a tag synonym for the former is unlikely. However, creating [birth-of-the-federation](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/birth-of-the-federation) as a tag synonym would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sure. [star-trek-botf](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/star-trek-botf) renamed to [star-trek-birth-of-the-federation](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/star-trek-birth-of-the-federation), and I've also made them synonyms.

Comment: Thanks! Can you also add [birth-of-the-federation] as a synonym, since that was one of the names the game was released under?